# Toda lattice solution for different algebras

Tags: condensed-matter, string-theory, mathematical-physics, integrable-systems, solitons

It is well-known that Toda systems (Toda field theory) can possess different algebraic structure based on Cartan Matrix in the Hamiltonian's potential.

But all solutions I have seen were written only for either Liouville (trivial) case or $A_2$ algebra.

I wonder if there exist (analytical) solutions for other (semi-) simple Lie algebras, e.g. $B_2, G_2, D_2$ (and higher dimensional if possible).

Thank you.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are looking for in the $A_2$ case ?

Comment: @user40085 something like this: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01390233